# How to delete a list from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I don't know how to delete a list from a list.

For example, There is a list.

```
box[1, 1] = {{50, {5, 3}}, {3.6463, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {81.490, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {20.2414, {5, 3}}, {42.439, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}};

select = RandomSample[box[1, 1], Take[5]];
```

Next, I want to create new list like newbox[1,1] = box[1,1] - select.

For example, If select is

```
select={{50, {5, 3}}, {42.439, {5, 3}}, {81.490, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}}
```

, newbox[1,1] should be

```
newbox[1,1]={{20.2414, {5, 3}},{50, {5, 3}}, {3.6463, {5, 3}},{50, {5, 3}},{50, {5, 3}}}
```

however, i couldn't make list, I don't understand how to use DeleteCases.for example, I tried

```
newbox[1, 1] = DeleteCases[box[1, 1], Alternatives @@ select]
```

but,Alternatives @@ select was incorrect because the same number(here is {50, {5, 3}}) of elements is recognised as one.

What equation should I construct?

Comment: I hope new list obtained by subtracting "select" from "box[1,1]".

Comment: They are not only selects, but also box[1,1] is actually a randomly generated list. I don't want specific values, but I want to avoid that elements with exactly the same value are not considered as one element and are selected in duplicate.

Comment: Yes,,,,,,,,,,,,,(, filling up of the minimum number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a slightly modified list:

```
orig = {{50, {5, 3}}, {3.6463, {5, 3}}, {51, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 
     3}}, {52, {5, 3}}, {81.490, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {20.2414, {5, 
     3}}, {42.439, {5, 3}}, {49, {5, 3}}};

select = {{50, {5, 3}}, {42.439, {5, 3}}, {81.490, {5, 3}}, {51, {5, 
    3}}, {50, {5, 3}}};
```

---

**Using `Complement`:** (which treats lists as sets)

```
Complement[orig, select]
```

> {{3.6463, {5, 3}}, {20.2414, {5, 3}}, {49, {5, 3}}, {52, {5, 3}}}

---

**Using `DeleteCases`:**

```
DeleteCases[orig, _?(MemberQ[select, #] &)]
```

> {{3.6463, {5, 3}}, {52, {5, 3}}, {20.2414, {5, 3}}, {49, {5, 3}}}

Comment: I am grateful for your assistance!

Comment: @hare, I am glad I was able to help. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DeleteElements` which came with V 13.1

It gives the desired result, but in a slightly different sort order.

```
 box =
  {{50, {5, 3}}, {3.6463, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}},
   {50, {5, 3}}, {81.490, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {20.2414, {5, 3}},
   {42.439, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}};

select =
 {{50, {5, 3}}, {42.439, {5, 3}}, {81.490, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}};

newbox = DeleteElements[box, 1 -> select]
```

{{3.6463, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {50, {5, 3}}, {20.2414, {5,
3}}, {50, {5, 3}}}

Comment: Thank you for your help!